# How can I reset localStorage at 00:00 every day?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

My problem is that I want to reset `localStorage` at `00:00` everyday.

Even if it's not `00:00`, I want to reset it at a specific time.
Is it possible to solve it through `setInterval` and `localStorage.clear()`?

Any advice is welcome. Thank you for answering the question.

Comment: What if the user doesn't have the page open at that time?

Answer (score 3):

Note that any code to reset `localStorage` does not guarantee to reset `localStorage` value, because user may not have the page open at that time.
So You can add custom expire time for your data like this:

```
function setWithExpiry(key, value, ttl) {
    const now = new Date()

    // `item` is an object which contains the original value
    // as well as the time when it's supposed to expire
    const item = {
        value: value,
        expiry: now.getTime() + ttl,
    }
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item))
}
```

And the get value function:

```
function getWithExpiry(key) {
    const itemStr = localStorage.getItem(key)
    // if the item doesn't exist, return null
    if (!itemStr) {
        return null
    }
    const item = JSON.parse(itemStr)
    const now = new Date()
    // compare the expiry time of the item with the current time
    if (now.getTime() > item.expiry) {
        // If the item is expired, delete the item from storage
        // and return null
        localStorage.removeItem(key)
        return null
    }
    return item.value
}
```

And the usage: (`TTL` value in in milliseconds)

```
setWithExpiry("myKey", some value, 5000)
```